# How to match cell colour of one to another

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me, as I am not very experienced with VBA.

Let's say I have the following cells with specific background colour. (Cells A3:A6)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru4Lm.jpg)

Now I would like cells (C3:C6) to copy the colour from A3:A6 and apply it to C3:C6.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxDqE.jpg)

I have seen this code being provided on the forum:

```
Dim xSRg, xDRg, xISRg, xIDRg As Range
Dim xFNum As Long
On Error Resume Next
Set xSRg = Range("C8:X8")
Set xDRg = Range("S16:AL16")
For xFNum = 1 To xSRg.count
Set xISRg = xSRg.Item(xFNum)
Set xIDRg = xDRg.Item(xFNum)
xIDRg.Interior.Color = xISRg.Interior.Color
Next xFNum
```

However, this code doesn't not work the cell colour has been applied by Conditional Formatting. What I mean is that this code works if I manually set the colour of cells (A3:A6) it will recognize the colour and simultaneously make C3:C6 match. But if the colour came from Conditional Formatting (say, make cell yellow if the cell is equal to 1). Please help me get a code that will recognize a colour set from Conditional formatting and change C3:C6 respectively. Thank you very much.

Comment: `.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` is the color applied by conditional formatting.

Comment: Would you please be able to provide a code that will be able to pull the colour applied by conditional formating and applied to the desired cell range?

Comment: Do you understand what `xIDRg.Interior.Color = xISRg.Interior.Color` is doing? Can you try on your own to modify it based on the first comment?

Comment: You may want to expand the range the conditional formatting applies to to include `C3:C6`

Comment: @BigBen I have attempted to replace xIDRg.DisplayFormat.Interior.Colour = xISRg.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color , however, did not get desired result. Please advise what I did wrong.

Comment: Did you try `xIDRg.Interior.Color = xISRg.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`?